# ambiguity in loops?

Tags: c#, datetime

The error I'm getting is "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled." It asks that **month** be between 1 and 12.  But look at the variable in the debugger says it equals to 1, along with a Debug.Writeline.

```
    int month, year, total;
    total = 0;
    DateTime dayToFind;

    for (year = 1001; year < 1201; year++){
        for (month = 1; month < 12; month++){
            dayToFind = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(month, year));
            // The error points at the last occurance of month above.
            total = (dayToFind.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday) ? 1 : 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `month = 1; month < 13` or are you intentionally skipping December?

Comment: Yeah, I typed that out too fast instead of just copying and pasting when I switched machines. Notice also `total =` should be `total +=`.  Unless I enjoy just looping and not actually aggregating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have your `DateTime.DaysInMonth()` call backwards.  Change it to this:

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)
```

When you put the `year` variable in the place of `month`, it was greater than the max that it can be (greater than 12), resulting in the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

[DateTime.DaysInMonth()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx)

Comment: @surfasb :) it happens to all of us.  There's nothing better than an extra set of eyes looking at it.

Comment: There is a song that goes, "I get by with a little help from my friends. . ."

Answer (score 2):

You reversed the arguments for the DaysInMonth method.  Year goes first.